# instanceOfT.getClass() not returning Class<? extends T>

Tags: java, generics

```java
<T> void foo(T bar) {
    final Class<? extends T> barType = bar.getClass();
}
```

This does not compile. `barType` is resolved to `capture of ? extends Object`. Doesn't make sense to me. Is java type inference so limited or do I miss something here?

Comment: Think about what happens when `T` is `ArrayList<String>`. Would `getClass` return `Class<ArrayList<String>>`? Well, that doesn't exist.

Comment: final Class<T> barType = bar.getClass();

Answer (score 0):

See the difference in the method definitions below. bar object in method call can get any type of value, so it is of the type `<? extends Object>` by default and not `<? extends T>`. Basically, T can be anything. So, at compile time it is by default Object type.

```
        <T> void foo(T bar) 
        {
            final Class<? extends Object> barType = bar.getClass();
        }
        
        <T> void foo(T bar) 
        {
            final Class<? extends T> barType = bar.getClass();
        }
```